# Problems setting up conditional search space in hyperopt

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, hyperparameters, hyperopt

I'll fully admit that I may be setting up the conditional space wrong here but for some reason, I just can't get this to function at all. I am attempting to use hyperopt to tune a logistic regression model and depending on the solver there are some other parameters that need to be explored. If you choose the liblinear solver you can choose penalties, and depending on the penalty you can also choose dual. When I try and run hyperopt on this search space though, it keeps giving me an error because its passing the entire dictionary as show below. Any ideas?

The error I'm getting is

```
ValueError: Logistic Regression supports only liblinear, newton-cg, lbfgs and sag solvers, got {'solver': 'sag'}'
```

This format worked when setting up a random forest search space so I'm at a loss.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
import pyodbc
import statsmodels as sm
from pandasql import sqldf
import math
from tqdm import tqdm
import pickle


from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler, OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score, cross_val_predict, train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold as StratifiedKFoldIt
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV, VarianceThreshold, SelectFromModel, SelectKBest
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, IncrementalPCA, FactorAnalysis
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier, BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionCV, SGDClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, precision_score, recall_score, accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix, f1_score, log_loss
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler, SMOTE, ADASYN 
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler, ClusterCentroids, NearMiss, NeighbourhoodCleaningRule, OneSidedSelection
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, Trials, STATUS_OK


space4lr = {
    'C': hp.uniform('C', .0001, 100.0),
    'solver' : hp.choice('solver', [
        {'solver' : 'newton-cg',},
        {'solver' : 'lbfgs',},
        {'solver' : 'sag'},
        {'solver' : 'liblinear', 'penalty' : hp.choice('penalty', [
             {'penalty' : 'l1'},
             {'penalty' : 'l2', 'dual' : hp.choice('dual', [True, False])}]
                                                      )},
    ]),
    'fit_intercept': hp.choice('fit_intercept', ['True', 'False']),
    'class_weight': hp.choice('class_weight', ['balanced', None]),
    'max_iter': 50000,
    'random_state': 84,
    'n_jobs': 8
}
lab = 0
results = pd.DataFrame()
for i in feature_elims:
target = 'Binary_over_3'

alt_targets = ['year2_PER', 'year2_GP' ,'year2_Min', 'year2_EFF' ,'year2_WS/40' ,'year2_Pts/Poss' ,'Round' ,'GRZ_Pick' 
               ,'GRZ_Player_Rating' ,'Binary_over_2', 'Binary_over_3' ,'Binary_over_4' ,'Binary_5' ,'Draft_Strength']
#alt_targets.remove(target)
nondata_columns = ['display_name' ,'player_global_id', 'season' ,'season_' ,'team_global_id', 'birth_date', 'Draft_Day']
nondata_columns.extend(alt_targets)

AGG_SET_CART_PERC = sqldf("""SELECT * FROM AGG_SET_PLAYED_ADJ_SOS_Jan1 t1 
                                 LEFT JOIN RANKINGS t2 ON t1.[player_global_id] = t2.[player_global_id]
                                 LEFT JOIN Phys_Training t3 ON t1.[player_global_id] = t3.[player_global_id]""")
AGG_SET_CART_PERC['HS_RSCI'] = AGG_SET_CART_PERC['HS_RSCI'].fillna(110)
AGG_SET_CART_PERC['HS_Avg_Rank'] = AGG_SET_CART_PERC['HS_Avg_Rank'].fillna(1)
AGG_SET_CART_PERC['HS_years_ranked'] = AGG_SET_CART_PERC['HS_years_ranked'].fillna(0)
AGG_SET_CART_PERC = shuffle(AGG_SET_CART_PERC, random_state=8675309)

rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=8675309)
ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=8675309)
rs = RobustScaler()

X = AGG_SET_CART_PERC
y = X[target]
X = pd.DataFrame(X.drop(nondata_columns, axis=1))
position = pd.get_dummies(X['position'])
for idx, row in position.iterrows():
    if row['F/C'] == 1:
        row['F'] = 1
        row['C'] = 1
    if row['G/F'] == 1:
        row['G'] = 1
        row['F'] = 1
position = position.drop(['F/C', 'G/F'], axis=1)
X = pd.concat([X, position], axis=1).drop(['position'], axis=1)
X = rs.fit_transform(X, y=None)
X = i.transform(X)

def hyperopt_train_test(params):    
    clf = LogisticRegression(**params)
    #cvs = cross_val_score(xgbc, X, y, scoring='recall', cv=skf).mean()
    skf = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=6, shuffle=False, random_state=1)
    metrics = []
    tuning_met = []
    accuracy = []
    precision = []
    recall = []
    f1 = []
    log = []
    for i, (train, test) in enumerate(skf):
        X_train = X[train]
        y_train = y[train]
        X_test = X[test]
        y_test = y[test]
        X_train, y_train = ros.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
        X_train, y_train = rus.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
        tuning_met.append((((precision_score(y_test, y_pred))*4) + recall_score(y_test, y_pred))/5)
        accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
        precision.append(precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
        recall.append(recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
        f1.append(f1_score(y_test, y_pred))
        log.append(log_loss(y_test, y_pred))
    metrics.append(sum(tuning_met) / len(tuning_met))
    metrics.append(sum(accuracy) / len(accuracy))
    metrics.append(sum(precision) / len(precision))
    metrics.append(sum(recall) / len(recall))
    metrics.append(sum(f1) / len(f1))
    metrics.append(sum(log) / len(log))
    return(metrics)

best = 0
count = 0

def f(params):
    global best, count, results, lab, met
    met = hyperopt_train_test(params.copy())
    met.append(params)
    met.append(featureset_labels[lab])
    acc = met[0]
    results = results.append([met])
    if acc > best:
        print(featureset_labels[lab],'new best:', acc, 'Accuracy:', met[1], 'Precision:', met[2], 'Recall:', met[3], 'using', params, """
        """)
        best = acc
    else:
        print(acc, featureset_labels[lab], count)
    
    count = count + 1
    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK}
 
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(f, space4lr, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=1000, trials=trials)
print(featureset_labels[lab], ' best:')
print(best, """
""")
lab = lab + 1
```

Comment: You should post the complete stack trace of error and the complete code which you are using. Also which version of scikit are you using. From the current [documentation of Logistic Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), it does support the `sag` solver.

Comment: The issue is that hyperopt its passing the entire {'solver': 'sag'}' dictionary instead of just 'sag'. If I run a singular experiment with any of the solvers it works just fine. Its a problem with how the hyperopt search space is setup. Also, if i dont put in the other conditions and just have the solvers written like 'solver' : hp.choice('solver', ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'sag', 'liblinear']), it works just fine as well. Its when I try and code in the conditional search space to add in the 'penalty' and 'dual' parameters that it stops working.

Comment: Can you post the full code that is generating this error?

Comment: Just posted the full code

Comment: The way you are trying to setup conditional parameters, I havent found any documentation which says its possible. Are you using any tutorial, or for any other estimator, this is working?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't include loaded modules

Comment: I set it up this way in random forest and it seems to be working properly. You said "the way I set it up" is there another way to set it up that you know of? Also, I added all of the imports. Its a very large script so I just added all the imports for the whole thing.

Comment: I am currently bypassing the problem by running hyperopt over three different logistic regression search spaces independently and then comparing the results but would be thrilled if someone knew a better way to set up the space with conditions!

Answer (score 0):

Though replying too late, but yesterday I faced this issue. Below mentioned code snippet, I think will help you out.

```
space = hp.choice('classifier',[
                      {
                       'model': LogisticRegression,
                       'param':
                         {
                             'hyper_param_groups' :hp.choice('hyper_param_groups',
                                             [
                                                {
                                                 'penalty':hp.choice('penalty_block1', ['l2']),
                                                 'solver':hp.choice('solver_block1', ['newton-cg', 'sag', 'saga', 'lbfgs']),
                                                 'multi_class':hp.choice('multi_class', ['ovr', 'multinomial']),
                                                },
                                                {
                                                 'penalty':hp.choice('penalty_block2', ['l2']),
                                                 'solver':hp.choice('solver_block2', ['liblinear']),
                                                 'multi_class':hp.choice('multi_class_block2', ['ovr']),
                                                },
                                                {
                                                 'penalty':hp.choice('penalty_block3', ['l1']),
                                                 'solver':hp.choice('solver_block3', ['saga']),
                                                 'multi_class':hp.choice('multi_class_block3', ['ovr', 'multinomial']),
                                                },
                                             ]),    
                            'dual':hp.choice('dual', [False]),
                            'class_weight':hp.choice('class_weight', ['balanced', None]),
                            'random_state':hp.choice('random_state', [10,267]),
                            'max_iter':hp.choice('max_iter', [100,500]),
                            'verbose':hp.choice('verbose', [0])
                         }
                      }])
```

and how to use it in callable method:

```
        penalty = args['param']['hyper_param_groups']['penalty']
        solver = args['param']['hyper_param_groups']['solver']
        multi_class = args['param']['hyper_param_groups']['multi_class']
        dual = args['param']['dual']
        class_weight = args['param']['class_weight']
        random_state = args['param']['random_state']
        max_iter = args['param']['max_iter']
        verbose = args['param']['verbose']
```